# PS tags does not work

Tags: ps

I run a ps command inside a startup script, if I put in:

```
ps -A -o euser,pid...
```

I get this output:

```
EUSER      PID CMD                         %CPU   RSS    SZ     ELAPSED 
root       644 ./code                       0.0   996  2963       00:00
```

It's there each time.

If I run:

```
ps -C ./code -o euser....
```

it does not display anything at all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you literally type “`ps -A -o euser,pid...`” and “`ps -C ./code -o euser....`”? I don't know of any system that accepts `...` or `....` here: what operating system are you using? If you actually typed something else and not the dots: copy-paste what you typed, exactly. It may be relevant. And do tell us which unix variant you're running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `ps -C` with just the bare script name (i.e. without `./`).  e.g.

`ps -C code -o euser....`